# Cuchichear - ¿Dónde se usa y qué significa?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, guatemala

Uno de mis clientes de Guatemala no entendió lo que es un susurro, pero sí entendió *cuchicheo* ("a whisper" en inglés).

¿En qué otras regiones se usa el verbo cuchichear?

Comment: En Colombia se usa y además de sinónimo de susurro (whisper) es sinónimo de chisme (gossip)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>Creo esta respuesta wiki para que aportemos en que regiones se usa la palabra cuchicheo y como se usa.</sub>

Cuchicheo se usa en las siguientes regiones:

**Argentina**
Hablar en voz baja y con apuro (acompáñese definición con gesto manual de abrir y cerrar la boca); suele implicar chismorreo.

**Colombia**
Se usa y además de sinónimo de susurro (whisper) es sinónimo de chisme (gossip)

**Chile**
Igual que en Colombia, pero también se aplica a las conversaciones románticas aunque no sean en voz baja. En el campo se usa mucho la forma "cuchuchiar".

**España**
Igual que en Colombia.

**Guatemala**
Susurro

**México**
Susurrar o chismear (en voz baja).

**Puerto Rico**
Bochinchear, hacer alboroto.

Comment: Nótese que el diccionario de americanismos registra una sola acepción de [_cuchichear_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=P1ltPVui0x0AtWhPLXo): _Puerto Rico. bochinchear, hacer alboroto_. Por tanto, entiendo que aplica la definición del [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BY530q4) _Hablar en voz baja o al oído a alguien, de modo que otros no se enteren_, por lo que la respuesta vendría a ser "se usa por todo". @Rodrigo: curiosamente, la etimología dice que viene de _cuchichiar_, a medio camino de lo que comentas que se usa en el campo de Chile.

Comment: En Argentina también se usa. Como dice DGaleano, también aquí se combinan los conceptos de susurro y chisme. El hablar en voz baja hace a la esencia del cuchicheo. El chisme sólo se intuye o presume, pues tal vez se cuchichee sin chusmear.